# Edit css and add jquery to some tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this issue going on.
I want to make something to check on some grades on a list of tables, and if its over or equal to 5 it should put a red lone across it. The following code is a list with 3 courses.

If you run the html code you will see that the grades are 5 .. 2.5 ... 7.5

And when i run to jsfiddle

```js
$('.topBorderLight').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var grade = Number($this.text());
    if(!isNaN(grade)) {
        $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade >= 5);
    }
});
```

```css
.gradeOver5,
.gradeOver5 td {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="groupHeader">Semester A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" class="italicHeader">
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">Course</td>
                    <td valign="top">Type</td>
                    <td valign="top">SM</td>
                    <td valign="top">Hours</td>
                    <td valign="top">ECTS</td>
                    <td valign="top">GRADE</td>
                    <td valign="top">Exam</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" bgcolor="#fafafa">
                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;<img align="absbottom" src="images/course4.gif" width="16"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="topBorderLight">(Ν2-1011)&nbsp; PHYSICS<span class="redfonts"></span></td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">COMPULSORY</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 6</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">6</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 7</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"><span class="redFonts">5</span></td>
                    <td nowrap="true" class="topBorderLight"><span class="tablecell"><i>Α WINTER&nbsp;
                        2012-2013</i></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="groupHeader">Semester A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" class="italicHeader">
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">Course</td>
                    <td valign="top">Type</td>
                    <td valign="top">SM</td>
                    <td valign="top">Hours</td>
                    <td valign="top">ECTS</td>
                    <td valign="top">GRADE</td>
                    <td valign="top">Exam</td>
                </tr>                   
                
<tr height="25" bgcolor="#fafafa" class="gradeOver5">
   <td valign="top">&nbsp;<img align="absbottom" src="images/course1.gif" width="16"></td>
   <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="topBorderLight">(Ν2-4021)&nbsp;PRO<span class="redfonts"></span></td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">COMPULSORY</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 4</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">4</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 4</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"><span class="redFonts">7.5</span></td>
   <td nowrap="true" class="topBorderLight"><span class="tablecell"><i>A WINTER&nbsp;
      2014-2015</i></span>
   </td>
</tr>



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="groupHeader">Semester A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" class="italicHeader">
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">Course</td>
                    <td valign="top">Type</td>
                    <td valign="top">SM</td>
                    <td valign="top">Hours</td>
                    <td valign="top">ECTS</td>
                    <td valign="top">GRADE</td>
                    <td valign="top">Exam</td>
                </tr>
                
<tr height="25" bgcolor="#fafafa" class="gradeOver5">
   <td valign="top">&nbsp;<img align="absbottom" src="images/course1.gif" width="16"></td>
   <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="topBorderLight">(Ν2-4021)&nbsp; SAE1<span class="redfonts"></span></td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">COMPULSORY</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 4</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">4</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 6</td>
   <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"><span class="redFonts">2.5</span></td>
   <td nowrap="true" class="topBorderLight"><span class="tablecell"><i>A WINTER&nbsp;
      2014-2015</i></span>
   </td>
</tr>



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that it is putting the line in the grade of 2.5 and not in the grade 5.

Could someone help me find the tricky part here?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your numbers are using commas rather than decimals. Try changing them to decimals and get back to me

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne edited. still the problem remains, but the normal html code that the website has my grades it is with commas.

Comment: I've just put your code into JSFiddle and it works perfectly fine. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Same here, just added your code to the js fiddle and it works fine

Comment: It doesn't work with commas though, so there is an issue there.

Comment: I've posted an updated version of your script which allows for the use of commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your code works perfectly fine in JSFiddle you want to alter your jQuery slightly so that it looks like this. This is just to handle the possibility of potential commas instead of decimals in your numbers as the `Number` class doesn't like a number in the format `2,5` and would prefer `2.5`

```
$('.topBorderLight').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    text = text.replace(',', '.');
    var grade = Number(text);
    if(!isNaN(grade)) {
        $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade >= 5);
    }
});
```

See a working version of this using commas in the grades [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7c26myp8/)

Answer (score 1):

I just added your code to the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs3ckdky/) and using the newest version of jquery and it works fine.

```
$('.topBorderLight').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
var grade = Number($this.text());
if(!isNaN(grade)) {
    $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade >= 5);
}
});
```

Comment: I provided him with a js fiddle link to show him that it seem to work just fine. Reason that i link the code is that you aint allowed to post jsfiddle links without. And last it looks better than posting links in coments

Answer (score 0):

Your other columns (SM/Hours/ECTS) are also parsing as numbers so they are triggering in the loop, try adding a class to just the grades:

```
...
<td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"><span class="redFonts grade">5</span></td>
...
```

Then upgrade the jquery:

```
$('.grade').each(function(){
...
```

Comment: Not strictly true. Although yes this should be the way its done, as the grade is the final column, it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: it only will toggle the class for a number less than 5, so at the moment you need an odd number of iterations for the code to work

Comment: Greater than 5 its `grade >= 5` but anyway, I've just tested and it doesn't matter how many odd or even it still works